Homomorphisms between Indecomposable Modules
Let $M$ be $K$-vector space (where $K$ is field) and suppose it is a module of finite length over an algebra $A$. By the Krull-Schmidt theorem we have that there is a decomposition
$$M = M_1 \oplus M_2 \oplus \dots M_n \tag{1}$$
into indecomposable A-submodules which is unique up to permutation and isomorphism. Let $M_i = N_i \oplus K_i$ where $N_i$ is the simple submodule of $M_i$ and $K_i$ is some vector space (not necessarily a submodule) for $i = 1, \dots, n$.
Moreover, by a generalisation of Schur's lemma we have that every endomorphism of $M_i$ is either invertible or nilpotent.
I have the following questions.

If $M_i$ and $M_j$ are inequivalent $A$-modules, then what can we say about $\textrm{Hom}_A(M_i, M_j)$? Will it always be $\{0\}$? Or will it depend if $N_i$ and $N_j$ are equivalent $A$-modules?
If $M_i$ and $M_j$ are equivalent $A$-modules then what can we say about $\textrm{Hom}_A(M_i, M_j)$? Will it always be in bijection with $K$?
Let $\alpha$ be an endomorphism of $M_1$. Does $\alpha$ always restrict to $N_1$? In particular, if $\alpha$ is nilpotent then does $\alpha(N_1) = \{0\}$?

I suspect the answer for the first two questions are no, but I am not familiar enough about modules to come up with any examples. I believe the answer to the third question is yes but I can't find any references. In general, it would be much appreciated if anyone could provide references on homomorphisms of indecomposable modules. All I could find were the two results mentioned above.

What do you mean by "equivalent modules"? Also you said $M_i$ is indecomposable but then write $M_i = N_i\oplus K_i$. What do you mean by that?

@Lomp By equivalent modules I mean isomorphic modules. Sorry, I should have been clearer, in the decomposition I meant $K_i$ to be some vector space and not necessarily a sub-module. I have made that clearer now.

Thanks for the clarification. Firstly you might have an indecomposable decomposition where your socle is not simple, for instance K[x,y]/<x^2, y^2, xy>. This contradicts what you said about $M_i$. Secondly you might consider the ring $R$ of upper triangular 2x2 matrices with coefficient in a field K. The 2 columns give you the indecomposable decomposition of $R$ as left module, say $R=C_1\oplus C_2$. You have $C_1\not\simeq C_2$ but $C_1$ embeds into $C_2$.

@Lomp Yep I see. Thanks for the example with the triangular matrices.

An indecomposable module $M$ is one which cannot be written non-trivially as a direct sum, so $M=N_1\oplus N_2$ implies one of the $N_i$ is zero.
Next, a finite length indecomposable module may have many simple submodules, not just one, and these may or may not be isomorphic. The sum of all simple submodules of $M$ is called the socle of $M$.
So one cannot in general claim that $N_i$ is the simple submodule of $M_i$, and one cannot write $M_i=N_i\oplus K_i$.
An example here would be to take the algebra $A=K[x,y]$ and the 3-dimensional module $M=A/(x,y)^2$, having basis (the images of) $1,x,y$. Then the span of $x,y$ is a 2-dimensional semi-simple submodule of $M$. It is isomorphic to the direct sum of two copies of the simple $A$-module $K=A/(x,y)$.
Another example would be to take the algebra of matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}\ast&0&0\\\ast&\ast&0\\\ast&0&\ast\end{bmatrix}$. Considering the natural left action on 3-space, this is an indecomposable module, containing non-isomorphic simple modules $Ke_2$ and $Ke_3$.
Finally, that endomorphisms of indecomposable modules are either invertible or nilpotent is usually referred to as Fitting’s Lemma.
Now to your questions.
(1) If $M_1,M_2$ are non-isomorphic indecomposable modules, then there may or may not be homomorphism beteeen them, independently of their socles. If there is a non-zero map, though, then by considering the image we see that the $M_i$ must contain some common simple composition factors.
There is a notion of radical morphism, however, analogous to the Jacobson radical of a ring, and every morphism between the $M_i$ must be radical.
(2) The endomorphism ring of an indecomposable module can be arbitrarily complicated. As a quick example, take any finite dimensional local algebra $A$. Then the regular representation, so $A$ itself as an $A$-module, has endomorphism ring $A$ (or its opposite, depending on your conventions…).
(3) Certain ‘characteristic’ submodules are invariant under endomorphisms. This includes the socle, and its dual notion the radical. So if $\alpha$ is an endomorphism of $M$, then $\alpha(\mathrm{soc}\,M)\subseteq\mathrm{soc}\,M$. If $\alpha$ is nilpotent, then it restricts to a nilpotent endomorphism of the socle.
Here’s an example showing an endomorphism whose restriction to the socle is not zero. Again let $A=K[x,y]$ and construct a 4-dimensional indecomposable module $M$ having basis $a,b,c,d$ and left $A$-action
$$ xa=c, \quad xb=d, \quad xc=xd=0 $$
$$ ya=d, \quad yb=yc=yd=0 $$
The socle of $M$ is $Kc\oplus Kd$.
Now there is an endomorphism $\alpha$ of $M$ with
$$ \alpha(a)=b, \quad \alpha(c)=d, \quad
\alpha(b)=\alpha(d)=0 $$
Thus its restriction to the socle of $M$ is the non-zero nilpotent endomorphism $c\mapsto d\mapsto 0$.
